# Search for most common "data" with mongoose, mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

My structure.

```
User: 
{
  name: "One",
  favoriteWorkouts: [ids of workouts],
  workouts: [ { name: "My workout 1" },...]
}
```

I want to get list of favorits/hottest workouts from database.

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $unwind : "$favorite" },
    { $group : { _id : "$favorite" , number : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { number : -1 } }
)
```

This returns

```
{
    "hot": [
    {
       "_id": "521f6c27145c5d515f000006",
       "number": 1
    },
    {
       "_id": "521f6c2f145c5d515f000007",
       "number": 1
    },...
]}
```

But I want

```
{
   hot: [
   {object of hottest workout 1, object of hottest workout 2,...}
]}
```

How do you sort hottest data and fill the result with object, not just ids?

Comment: Where's the data that maps to the `_id`s stored in the `favoriteWorkouts` array? There are no joins in MongoDB, so you'd need to do it as a second step possibly.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to want to use MongoDB's aggregation framework. Aggregation will give you the output you are looking for if used correctly.  If you are looking for just a list of the _id's of all users' favorite workouts, then I believe that you would need to add an additional $group operation to your pipeline:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $unwind : "$favoriteWorkouts" },
    { $group : { _id : "$favoriteWorkouts", number : { $sum : 1 } } },
    { $sort : { number : -1 } },
    { $group : { _id : "oneDocumentWithWorkoutArray", hot : { $push : "$_id" } } }  
)
```

This will yield a document of the following form, with the workout ids listed by popularity:

```
{
    "_id" : "oneDocumentWithWorkoutArray",
    "hot" : [
        "workout6",
        "workout1",
        "workout5",
        "workout4",
        "workout3",
        "workout2"
    ]
}
```